# Drupal 6 -->Drupal 7 delete content_ tables

Tags: drupal

Can I safely delete content_* tables from drupal 7 after cck migration?

Answer (score 1):

Those database tables are not used in Drupal 7, where the content of entity fields is saved in field_data_* and field_revision_* tables. Before to delete any content_* table, be sure that you migrated any CCK field you were using with Drupal 6; if there is a CCK module that still needs to be ported to Drupal 7, then you could need keeping the database tables containing the data for the fields handled by that module.